# eventualmente/eventually: questione di prospettiva?

Tags: etymology, english-comparison

Mi ricordo vagamente di aver letto da qualche parte una spiegazione "culturale" al diverso significato di eventualmente ed eventually. Purtroppo non ricordo con precisione, ma era qualcosa del tipo: per la cultura inglese gli eventi rappresentano la via metodo per arrivare alla conclusione "eventually" , mentre per la cultura italiana gli eventi possono essere sfavorevoli, quindi qualcosa accade "eventualmente".
E' questa la motivazione della differenza di significato fra eventually e eventualmente?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In italiano, *eventuale* indica qualcosa che può accadere oppure no. Ma il latino *eventus* indicava un evento, un caso (anche fortunato) o un destino; un significato correlato è quello di “risultato di un'azione” (si veda il dizionario [Lewis-Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3atext:1999.04.0059%3aentry=eventus)) e questo è passato in inglese. L'aggettivo *eventual* è modellato su *actual*, secondo l'[Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/eventual?q=eventual), ma come aggettivo di [*event*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/event?q=event), cioè “qualcosa che accade”.

Non credo sia una questione di differenze culturali; l'inglese ha preso *event* nel sedicesimo secolo, con il significato originale latino. In italiano ha prevalso, come significato di *eventuale*, quello legato all'incertezza.

Comment: Allora forse l'ho letto in qualche blog o articolo dove si voleva piu' che altro filosofeggiare sulle differenze culturali!